# MariaDB / pymysql: Data shows up in columns as hex values (0x5761746572 instead of "Water")

Tags: mysql, unicode, mariadb, pymysql

I'm trying to create a local Docker image that represents a development version of my production database. I've started a MariaDB container with the same version as production (10.1) and loaded a schema based on a mysqldump of production.

However when I start inserting data, I get weird hex values in every column.

The production data looks like:

```
select * from projects where p_project = 'Water';
+-----------+----------------+------------+----------+-------------+---------+----------+----------+---------+--------------------+
| p_project | p_timestamp    | p_wikipage | p_parent | p_shortname | p_count | p_qcount | p_icount | p_scope | p_upload_timestamp |
+-----------+----------------+------------+----------+-------------+---------+----------+----------+---------+--------------------+
| Water     | 20200305045828 | NULL       | NULL     | NULL        |     841 |      644 |      554 |       0 | 20190813001026     |
+-----------+----------------+------------+----------+-------------+---------+----------+----------+---------+--------------------+
```

While the dev database looks like:

```
select * from projects where p_project = 'Water';
+----------------------+--------------------------------+------------------------+--------------------+--------------------------+---------+----------+----------+---------+----------------------------------------+
| p_project            | p_timestamp                    | p_wikipage             | p_parent           | p_shortname              | p_count | p_qcount | p_icount | p_scope | p_upload_timestamp                     |
+----------------------+--------------------------------+------------------------+--------------------+--------------------------+---------+----------+----------+---------+----------------------------------------+
| 0x5761746572         | 0x3230323030333035303532333538 | 0x                     | 0x                 | 0x                       |    NULL |     NULL |     NULL |       0 | 0x                                     |
+----------------------+--------------------------------+------------------------+--------------------+--------------------------+---------+----------+----------+---------+----------------------------------------+
```

The production database is defined as so:

```
show create database enwp10;
enwp10 | CREATE DATABASE `enwp10` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci */ |
```

And dev is:

```
show create database enwp10_dev;
| enwp10_dev | CREATE DATABASE `enwp10_dev` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci */ |
```

Here's the table definition:

```
show create table projects;
----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| projects | CREATE TABLE `projects` (
  `p_project` varbinary(63) NOT NULL,
  `p_timestamp` binary(14) NOT NULL,
  `p_wikipage` varbinary(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `p_parent` varbinary(63) DEFAULT NULL,
  `p_shortname` varbinary(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `p_count` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `p_qcount` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `p_icount` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `p_scope` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `p_upload_timestamp` binary(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`p_project`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+----------
```

The interesting part is that the select works in both cases, so maybe it's my mysql client display settings that are off?

My kwargs to my pymysql connect call include:

```
      'charset': None,
      'use_unicode': False,
```

Which has always worked perfectly fine in production. Additionally, I have set my global server charset to 'utf8mb4' and server collation to 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' for the development database.

All of the tables in the development database are defined with `CHARSET=latin1`, but that's also true for the production tables.

Any ideas what is going on here? Thanks!

Comment: This could be because on my dev machine I'm using: `$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.19 for osx10.14 on x86_64 (Homebrew)` and on production I'm using `$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.44-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2`. So the client binaries are different.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was using the `mysql` client binary that was installed by mysql, and the protocol must be slightly different with this old (10.1) version of MariaDB. See comment on question.

The solution was to install MariaDB for MacOS, at the proper version, and use `/usr/local/mariadb/server/bin/mariadb` to connect to my docker database.